# Python and Pandas: Using a function to replace text

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns (Line, Sentence) and I need to count the number of times the word "RESULT" appears in each sentence. but I don't want to count if it appears as "AS A RESULT" or "WAS THE RESULT", etc (the actual list is quite long and with other words).
I had this problem before in a list and I used a little trick: I replaced the string, run the count and them replace it back the original. see function below (version 1, first pass; version 2, second pass).

```py
def ConfusingStrings(text, version):
    if version == 1:
        text = re.sub(r"AS A RESULT", "XXXASAREXULT", text)
        text = re.sub(r"WAS THE RESULT", "XXXWASTHEREXULT", text)
    if version == 2:
        text = re.sub(r"XXXASAREXULT", "AS A RESULT", text)
        text = re.sub(r"XXXOFTHEREXULT", "OF THE RESULT", text)
    return text
```

Now, with the pandas dataframe, I am trying to use the apply function, see below, but to be honest I cannot get this to work.

```py
df['sentence'] = df.apply(ConfusingStrings(df['sentence'],1), axis=1)
```

Thanks for any input.

UPDATE:

```py
import pandas as pd
c = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':['ABC RESULTS FROM XYZ', 'AS A RESULT WE WILL NOT', 'THE RESULT IS THAT', 'THE BORDER WAS THE RESULT OF'], 'C':[1, 0,1,0]})
print (c)
```

The outcome I need is something like column C (which I did here manually), but bear in mind that this is a simplification, the list of confusing words/expression is in fact quite long, that's why I am looking to separate it in a function (easier to update and keeps main code cleaner). So basically I need to create column C via a function, I think.

Comment: also post the sample dataframe and the expected output (as text) which help users to reproduce the problem. also look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: I just created a dummy data frame to include `ab` and exclude the list `'fc ab', 'ab ac'`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B':['ab', 'ab ac', 'fc ab', 'ab', 'ab ac', 'fc ab']})

list_to_include = ['ab']
list_to_exclude = ['fc ab', 'ab ac']

df['match'] = df['B'].str.count(r'|'.join(list_to_include)) - df['B'].str.count(r'|'.join(list_to_exclude))
```

**match** is the column containing count. You can also put abs to include safety for non negative values.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I dont think it help as the list is not that simple. Can I ask you to please look at my update in the OP

Comment: If the list is not properly defined, maybe you should try POS and NER tagging in that case. Look for POS tagging which will reflect the context of words used. That will make sense while filtering.

Comment: I see where you are going, and it is a good solution. But at this stage I would prefer a coding solution. An alternative can be to create a temporary column with the replaced text, run the count on that column and then delete it. Simpler but I am still stuck as I struggling to get my head around how to manipulate text in a data frame.